# Is there solution for this error message (karma-typescript)?

Tags: javascript, typescript, karma-typescript

When I run `karma start` I get this message:

> Uncaught Error: Can't find entrypoint
>   [/home/sample/sampleproj/test/base.spec.ts] (required by commonjs.js) 
>   at node_modules/karma-typescript/dist/client/commonjs.js:13:17

How to solve this?

```
import 'zone.js/dist/zone';
import 'zone.js/dist/long-stack-trace-zone';
import 'zone.js/dist/proxy';
import 'zone.js/dist/sync-test';
import 'zone.js/dist/jasmine-patch';
import 'zone.js/dist/async-test';
import 'zone.js/dist/fake-async-test';
import { TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { BrowserDynamicTestingModule, platformBrowserDynamicTesting } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/testing';

TestBed.initTestEnvironment(BrowserDynamicTestingModule, platformBrowserDynamicTesting());
```

Comment: Maybe start with showing your code code in /home/sample/sampleproj/test/base.spec.ts, before you get downvoted